# method getColor(Context, int) is undefined in Facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, colors, facebook-android-sdk

[image: Problem]Hi I'm trying to import facebook sdk. I'm getting this error of undefined getColor in line `setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.com_facebook_blue));`. I've imported appcompat v7 library into the facebook sdk still its showing the error. Please let me know what can be done in this situation.

```html
public abstract class FacebookButtonBase extends Button {
    private String analyticsButtonCreatedEventName;
    private String analyticsButtonTappedEventName;
    private OnClickListener externalOnClickListener;
    private OnClickListener internalOnClickListener;
    private boolean overrideCompoundPadding;
    private int overrideCompoundPaddingLeft;
    private int overrideCompoundPaddingRight;
    private FragmentWrapper parentFragment;

    protected FacebookButtonBase(
            final Context context,
            final AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyleAttr,
            int defStyleRes,
            final String analyticsButtonCreatedEventName,
            final String analyticsButtonTappedEventName) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        defStyleRes = (defStyleRes == 0 ? this.getDefaultStyleResource() : defStyleRes);
        defStyleRes = (defStyleRes == 0 ? R.style.com_facebook_button : defStyleRes);
        configureButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        this.analyticsButtonCreatedEventName = analyticsButtonCreatedEventName;
        this.analyticsButtonTappedEventName = analyticsButtonTappedEventName;
    }

    protected abstract int getDefaultRequestCode();

    /**
     * Sets the fragment that contains this control. This allows the button to be embedded inside a
     * Fragment, and will allow the fragment to receive the
     * {@link Fragment#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent) onActivityResult}
     * call rather than the Activity.
     *
     * @param fragment the android.support.v4.app.Fragment that contains this control
     */
    public void setFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
        parentFragment = new FragmentWrapper(fragment);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the fragment that contains this control. This allows the button to be embedded inside a
     * Fragment, and will allow the fragment to receive the
     * {@link Fragment#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent) onActivityResult}
     * call rather than the Activity.
     *
     * @param fragment the android.app.Fragment that contains this control
     */
    public void setFragment(final android.app.Fragment fragment) {
        parentFragment = new FragmentWrapper(fragment);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the fragment that contains this control.
     * @return The android.support.v4.app.Fragment that contains this control.
     */
    public Fragment getFragment() {
        return (parentFragment != null) ? parentFragment.getSupportFragment() : null;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the fragment that contains this control.
     * @return The android.app.Fragment that contains this control.
     */
    public android.app.Fragment getNativeFragment() {
        return (parentFragment != null) ? parentFragment.getNativeFragment() : null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(final OnClickListener l) {
        this.externalOnClickListener = l;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the request code used for this Button.
     *
     * @return the request code.
     */
    public int getRequestCode() {
        return getDefaultRequestCode();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            logButtonCreated(getContext());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        boolean centered = (this.getGravity() & Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) != 0;
        if (centered) {
            // if the text is centered, we need to adjust the frame for the titleLabel based on the
            // size of the text in order to keep the text centered in the button without adding
            // extra blank space to the right when unnecessary
            // 1. the text fits centered within the button without colliding with the image
            //    (imagePaddingWidth)
            // 2. the text would run into the image, so adjust the insets to effectively left align
            //    it (textPaddingWidth)
            final int compoundPaddingLeft = getCompoundPaddingLeft();
            final int compoundPaddingRight = getCompoundPaddingRight();
            final int compoundDrawablePadding = getCompoundDrawablePadding();
            final int textX = compoundPaddingLeft + compoundDrawablePadding;
            final int textContentWidth = getWidth() - textX - compoundPaddingRight;
            final int textWidth = measureTextWidth(getText().toString());
            final int textPaddingWidth = (textContentWidth - textWidth) / 2;
            final int imagePaddingWidth = (compoundPaddingLeft - getPaddingLeft()) / 2;
            final int inset = Math.min(textPaddingWidth, imagePaddingWidth);
            this.overrideCompoundPaddingLeft = compoundPaddingLeft - inset;
            this.overrideCompoundPaddingRight = compoundPaddingRight + inset;
            this.overrideCompoundPadding = true;
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        this.overrideCompoundPadding = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCompoundPaddingLeft() {
        return (this.overrideCompoundPadding ?
                this.overrideCompoundPaddingLeft :
                super.getCompoundPaddingLeft());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCompoundPaddingRight() {
        return (this.overrideCompoundPadding ?
                this.overrideCompoundPaddingRight :
                super.getCompoundPaddingRight());
    }

    protected Activity getActivity() {
        Context context = getContext();
        while (!(context instanceof Activity) && context instanceof ContextWrapper) {
            context = ((ContextWrapper) context).getBaseContext();
        }

        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            return (Activity) context;
        }
        throw new FacebookException("Unable to get Activity.");
    }

    protected int getDefaultStyleResource() {
        return 0;
    }

    protected int measureTextWidth(final String text) {
        return (int)Math.ceil(getPaint().measureText(text));
    }

    protected void configureButton(
            final Context context,
            final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyleAttr,
            final int defStyleRes) {
        parseBackgroundAttributes(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        parseCompoundDrawableAttributes(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        parseContentAttributes(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        parseTextAttributes(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        setupOnClickListener();
    }

    protected void callExternalOnClickListener(final View v) {
        if (externalOnClickListener != null) {
            externalOnClickListener.onClick(v);
        }
    }

    protected void setInternalOnClickListener(final OnClickListener l) {
        internalOnClickListener = l;
    }

    private void logButtonCreated(final Context context) {
        AppEventsLogger logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(context);
        logger.logSdkEvent(analyticsButtonCreatedEventName, null, null);
    }

    private void logButtonTapped(final Context context) {
        AppEventsLogger logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(context);
        logger.logSdkEvent(analyticsButtonTappedEventName, null, null);
    }

    private void parseBackgroundAttributes(
            final Context context,
            final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyleAttr,
            final int defStyleRes) {
        // TODO, figure out why com_facebook_button_like_background.xml doesn't work in designers
        if (isInEditMode()) {
            return;
        }

        final int attrsResources[] = {
                android.R.attr.background,
        };
        final TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                attrsResources,
                defStyleAttr,
                defStyleRes);
        try {
            if (a.hasValue(0)) {
                int backgroundResource = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
                if (backgroundResource != 0) {
                    setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource);
                } else {
                    setBackgroundColor(a.getColor(0, 0));
                }
            } else {
                // fallback, if no background specified, fill with Facebook blue
                setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.com_facebook_blue));
             //setBackgroundColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(getContext(), R.color.com_facebook_blue));
            }
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    private void parseCompoundDrawableAttributes(
            final Context context,
            final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyleAttr,
            final int defStyleRes) {
        final int attrsResources[] = {
                android.R.attr.drawableLeft,
                android.R.attr.drawableTop,
                android.R.attr.drawableRight,
                android.R.attr.drawableBottom,
                android.R.attr.drawablePadding,
        };
        final TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                attrsResources,
                defStyleAttr,
                defStyleRes);
        try {
            setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                    a.getResourceId(0, 0),
                    a.getResourceId(1, 0),
                    a.getResourceId(2, 0),
                    a.getResourceId(3, 0));
            setCompoundDrawablePadding(a.getDimensionPixelSize(4, 0));

        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    private void parseContentAttributes(
            final Context context,
            final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyleAttr,
            final int defStyleRes) {
        final int attrsResources[] = {
                android.R.attr.paddingLeft,
                android.R.attr.paddingTop,
                android.R.attr.paddingRight,
                android.R.attr.paddingBottom,
        };
        final TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                attrsResources,
                defStyleAttr,
                defStyleRes);
        try {
            setPadding(
                    a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0),
                    a.getDimensionPixelSize(1, 0),
                    a.getDimensionPixelSize(2, 0),
                    a.getDimensionPixelSize(3, 0));
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    private void parseTextAttributes(
            final Context context,
            final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyleAttr,
            final int defStyleRes) {
        final int colorResources[] = {
                android.R.attr.textColor,
        };
        final TypedArray colorAttrs = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                colorResources,
                defStyleAttr,
                defStyleRes);
        try {
            setTextColor(colorAttrs.getColor(0, Color.WHITE));
        } finally {
            colorAttrs.recycle();
        }
        final int gravityResources[] = {
                android.R.attr.gravity,
        };
        final TypedArray gravityAttrs = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                gravityResources,
                defStyleAttr,
                defStyleRes);
        try {
            setGravity(gravityAttrs.getInt(0, Gravity.CENTER));
        } finally {
            gravityAttrs.recycle();
        }
        final int attrsResources[] = {
                android.R.attr.textSize,
                android.R.attr.textStyle,
                android.R.attr.text,
        };
        final TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                attrsResources,
                defStyleAttr,
                defStyleRes);
        try {
            setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, 0));
            setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(a.getInt(1, Typeface.BOLD)));
            setText(a.getString(2));
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    private void setupOnClickListener() {
        // set the listener on super so that consumers can set another listener that this will
        // forward to
        super.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                logButtonTapped(getContext());
                if (FacebookButtonBase.this.internalOnClickListener != null) {
                    FacebookButtonBase.this.internalOnClickListener.onClick(v);
                } else if (FacebookButtonBase.this.externalOnClickListener != null) {
                    FacebookButtonBase.this.externalOnClickListener.onClick(v);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of `appcompat v7` ?

Comment: how to check the version?

Comment: if its studio than from app's `build.gradle` file .or from project details

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ContextCompat, I used setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE) and it worked for me.